# How to solve this with discrete math *Pokemon Trainers!*

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There is a contest with 40 Pokemons. There are 18 Pokemons who like to ﬁght
in the sky, and 23 who like to ﬁght on ground. Several of them like to ﬁght in
water. The number of those who like to ﬁght in the sky and on ground is 9.
There are 7 Pokemons who like to ﬁght in the sky and in water, and 12 who
like to ﬁght on ground and in water. There are 4 Pokemons who like to ﬁght
in the sky, on ground, and in water. How many Pokemons like to ﬁght in water

How do i express this problem with discrete math?

Comment: Is there any pokemon who don't want to fight?

Comment: @Foool No Pokemon wants to fight, but Trainers can be so cruel...

Comment: [Venn diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram)

Comment: How would this work with venn diagram? Its possible?

Comment: S -set of pokemons who like to fight in the sky , W - set of pokemons who like to fight in water , G - set of pokemons who like to fight on the ground....Answer should be 23 .

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: i agree but let me try the venn version of your answer

Comment: This worked! venn diagram perfect

Comment: Wait shouldnt it be 6 because the 4 you would subtract?

Comment: from each overlappying category?

Comment: I mean 7 since it adds 11 then subtract 4 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let' denote : S -set of pokemons who like to fight in the sky , W - set of pokemons who like to fight in water , G - set of pokemons who like to fight on the ground .

[image]

$x=40-(4+3+5+8+6+6)=8$ , hence :

$P_W=3+4+8+8=23$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there every Pokemon wants to fight.

We can use [principle of inclusion and exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to solve this problem. 
If $x$ is the number of Pokemons like to ﬁght in water then,
$$40 = 18+23+x -(9+7+12) + 4 \Rightarrow x = 23$$

If there are Pokemon who don't want to fight then we need to subtract that number from the RHS of the equation and then solve for $x$.

Comment: Why do you call it "mutual"? If I understand correctly this is the same as what's otherwise just called "inclusion-exclusion"?

Answer (score 0):

$N(sky\cup ground\cup water)=N(sky)+N(ground)+N(water)-N(sky\cap ground)-N(sky\cap water)-N(ground \cap water)+N(sky\cap ground\cap water)$

where N(X) is number of pokemon that wants to fight in terrain X. This is called inclusion-exclusion principle.